# Reading multiple files with different number of lines

Tags: arrays, c, file-io, io

I am trying to read arrays from multiple files, and the array size in each file is different. So what I do is, I try to count the number of lines in the file and then store that as the array size.

For example, I have two .txt files, `File_1.txt` and `File_2.txt` which contain the following data:

```
0.000 300.00
0.054 2623.3
1.000 300.00
```

```
0.000 300.00
0.054 2623.3
0.500 1500.0
1.000 300.00
```

respectively.

Here is the code that I use:

```
int main()
{
    char filter[1024];
    char filename[60];
    FILE *fp;
    double *T_SR, Z_SR;

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sprintf(filename, "File_%d.txt", i);
        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            exit(1);
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int j = getc(fp); j != EOF; j = getc(fp))
        {
            if (j == '\n')
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }

        T_SR = (double *)malloc(count * sizeof(double));
        Z_SR = (double *)malloc(count * sizeof(double));

        for (int rows = 0; rows < count; rows++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf", &Z_SR[rows], &T_SR[rows]);
            printf("%lf %lf\n", Z_SR[rows], T_SR[rows]);
            if (feof(fp))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But instead of printing the given array as output, it prints this:

```
0.0000 0.0000
0.0000 0.0000
```

I checked the value of `count`, it's good. Maybe the problem is simple, but I am not able to find it. Can someone please help?

Comment: Your code shouldn't build. The variable `Z_SR` is ***not*** a pointer.

Comment: OT: the `(double *)` casts are not necessary with `malloc`. Actually no cast is ever needed with `malloc`, just write `... = malloc(...)`.

Comment: `double *T_SR, *Z_SR;` or better declare the variables separately, you'll avoid these mistakes.

Comment: Out of curiosity: which compiler are you using? The code you posted should not compile.

Comment: I would suggest using `fgets` to read lines, and using a linked list instead of an array.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful suggestions. They are really helpful. And for the compiler - gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 @Jabberwocky

Comment: @anastaciu what kind of errors are we talking about when I declare the variables like this `double *T_SR, *Z_SR;`, instead of declaring them separately?

Comment: @UdayCK Errors like forgetting the second asterisk.

Comment: Ah, of course! That was dumb. Sorry

Comment: In the last `for` loop, the break condition should be `if (fscanf(...) != 2) break;` That way, the `printf` won't be called when the `fscanf` fails, and you don't need the `feof` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you ran the whole file with `getc` the file indicator will be at the end of the file you must set it back to the beginning before you use `fscanf`, you can use `rewind` for that.

```
rewind(fp); //<--
for (int rows = 0; rows < count; rows++)
{
    //...
}
```

Aside from that, other problems exist as [Jaberwocky pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67208863/6865932), among others, like a memory leak issue, and the fact that you don't close your files or check `malloc` return, here's how your code could look like (with comments):

```
double *T_SR, *Z_SR; // fix the pointer issue
//...
char line[1024]; // make sure it's larger than the largest line in the file

while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) // fixes the count issue
{
    // doesn't count empty lines, if there are any
    if (line[0] != '\n')
    {
         count++;
    }
}
if(count > 0)
{
    T_SR = malloc(count * sizeof *T_SR);
    Z_SR = malloc(count * sizeof *Z_SR);
    if(T_SR == NULL || Z_SR == NULL) // check memory allocation
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    rewind(fp);
    for(int rows = 0; fscanf(fp, "%lf%lf", &Z_SR[rows], &T_SR[rows]) == 2; rows++)
    {
         printf("%lf %lf\n", Z_SR[rows], T_SR[rows]);
    }
    free(T_SR); // free the memory, avoids memory leaks
    free(Z_SR);
}
fclose(fp); // and close the file
//...
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0gIITfuyh4uYqJyQ)

Comment: @UdayCK, I added a possible implementation, fixing the other problems.

Comment: This is very nice. Thanks a lot. But instead of `T_SR` and `Z_SR`, let us say we had many arrays like that. Do I have to hardcode everything? For ex: `if(T_SR==NULL || Z_SR == NULL || CH4_SR == NULL || ....`). Or is there a simpler way? @anastaciu

Comment: @UdayCK, if the arrays are individually named and allocated, then yes, but you can have an array of arrays to store all of them there using a pointer to array, in that case only one allocation and deallocation is needed, a [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=memory+allocation+for+pointer+to+array) rendered me some SO posts that teach how to do this, if you don't find them helpful ask a new question, it looks interesting to me and would be for sure well received.

Answer (score 3):

There are several bugs:

1. The most important one is the `rewind` issue that has been addressed in anastaciu's anwer.
2. `double * T_SR, Z_SR` is wrong, it should be `double * T_SR, *Z_SR`. I wonder actually if the code you posted is the code you compile.
3. your line counting method is flawed. If the last line of the file does not end with a `\n`, the `count` variable will be 2 and you'll miss the last line.
4. `fscanf` returns the number of items read or `EOF`. If you had check that, you might have found the problem in your code yourself.
5. the `feof` check is done too late, if `fscanf` encounters en EOF you still print the values that have not bee read due to the EOF condition.

Comment: Very helpful suggestions. In fact, I forgot the second asterisk while posting the code on StackOverflow. I understood all the points that you have posted except for the third. I don't understand what you mean when you say if the last line does not end with \n. Can you please elaborate? @Jabberwocky

Comment: @UdayCK open your text editor to create a new file, type `123`, don't press Enter and save the file. Now that file contains one line that _does not_ end with a `\n`. Now open that file again in the text editor, put the cursor right after the `3`, press Enter and save the file. Now that file contains one line that _does_ end with a `\n`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. It prints zero when there is an empty line at the end of the file. Thanks again. @Jabberwocky

Comment: To ignore the last line that does not end with `\n`, I made a condition like this. `int last = '\n' ;` and then `if (j == '\n' && last !='\0') count = count + 1 ` . But it still prints the last line. What am I doing wrong? @Jabberwocky

Comment: @UdayCK you should ask another question for this specific problem. Like "How to count the number of lines in a file?". Maybe there is already a duplicate.

Comment: @UdayCK like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751837/counting-number-of-lines-in-the-file-in-c. Or just google "Counting number of lines in the file in C"

Answer (score 2):

> I try to count the number of lines in the file and then store that as the array size.

Aside from the key `rewind()` issue, avoid reading code one way to find line count and another to find the `double`s.  Far too easy to get a line count that does not match the "line count" of reading two `double`s.

Use **one** approach to find both.

```
size_t read_SR(size_t count, double *Z_SR, double *T_SR, FILE *inf) {
  char line[100];
  rewind(inf);
  size_t rows;
  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, inf)) {
    double Z, T; 
    if (sscanf(line, "%lf %lf", &Z, &T) != 2) return rows;
    if (rows < count) {
      if (Z_SR) Z_SR[rows] = Z;
      if (T_SR) T_SR[rows] = T;
    }
    rows++;
  }
  return rows;
}
```

Usage

```
// First pass, find size
size_t count = read_SR(0, NULL, NULL, inf);
double *T_SR = malloc(sizeof *T_SR * count);
double *Z_SR = malloc(sizeof *Z_SR * count);
// 2nd pass, save data
read_SR(count, Z_SR, T_SR, inf);
```